# Tomcat on centos behaves differently from tomcat on mac?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, centos7

I am developing my spring mvc application on a mac and tried different tomcat versions there. All worked fine.
When I deploy the war to a tomcat residing on centos 7, the application overall works fine as well. But there are some issues, I couldn't find the root cause for:

1) Symbols of font-awesome do not show on centos-tomcat. The font is provided by the war and I checked, that the references do work.

2) The unit tests during the build (jenkins on the centos machine) are getting some errors, when reading property files. It seems like some entries of that property files are not read. However, most entries work fine, and I don't see obvious differences.

3) a favicon of type *.ico could not be rendered. After renaming it to *.gif, it worked fine.

4) a third-party javascript produces odd results, which might be a consequence of 2)

Do you have some hints, what I could check?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause. In my pom.xml I had a filtering activated, which kept some resources out of the war file. When I tested locally, I started the application by eclipse and this error was not seen.

This change helped:

```
<webResources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
</webResources>
```